# Dockerfile: Copy command on windows container fails with "Access Denied"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am trying to run a web application implemented with php, js, html together with Selenium to test functionality. I am using a python script together with pytest to run the selenium tests against the web application. The web application is already dockerized with a windows/servercore:ltsc2019 base image and the xampp application. If the dockerfile is build for the first time it succeeds. But if some changes are done and the container has to be rebuilded i get the following error:

```
Status: failed to copy files: failed to copy directory: chtimes \\?\Volume{06ac6f98-32bd-4e73-b16b-f982f49c7bd6}\xampp\htdocs\img: Access denied
```

on this Dockerfile step:

```
Step 2/7 : COPY . C:\\xampp\\htdocs
```

I am using the already dockerized web application (including docker-compose) and an existing gitlab pipeline. After adding selenium and python services to docker-compose I found out that they are only available on linux containers so I switched the docker engine to experimental to make use of the mixed mode. And that was working just fine for my pc at work (I tested it there). But then I used the same docker-compose file on my home pc and I got the error from above. Also on the gitlab-runner that runs the pipeline the same error occured after modifying the pipeline slightly (Added point 2-4).

1. Run web application container

```
docker-compose -f ./docker/stage/docker-compose-staging.yml --compatibility up --build -d
```

2. Switch daemon to linux container with powershell script

```
./docker-e2e-tests/SwitchDaemon.ps1
```

3. Run the test containers (Selenium, python)

```
docker-compose -f ./docker-e2e-tests/docker-compose.yml --compatibility up --build -d
```

4. Switch daemon back to windows container with powershell script

```
./docker-e2e-tests/SwitchDaemon.ps1
```

Same result here. First time it was fine. Second time I tried to COPY the changes into the container (step 1) I got the same error as above. And now the worst problem is, that the pipeline is not running anymore at all. I am even getting the same error now if I remove step 2-4.